# skphysicsbody collision between two same nodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I created a class that declare a ball of kind 'SKShapeNode'. in its init I set the 'SKPhysicsBody' properties. before I set these properties (leave it as default) when one ball touch another one the both affected by the touch (like: move to different position depends on the collision position). after I set the 'physicsBody' properties it won't affected any more - one ball appear to be above the other one (like frame on frame - hiding it). how can I set this property? I look at apple doc and did find nothing...
here is my code:

```
lass BallNode: SKShapeNode {
    var radius:CGFloat = 0
    var color:UIColor?
    var strokeWidth:CGFloat = 0
    private var _name:String?

override init() {
        super.init()
        self.fillColor = ranColor()
        self.lineWidth = strokeWidth

    }

convenience init(radius:CGFloat){
        self.init(circleOfRadius: radius)
        self.radius = radius
        self.physicsBody  = SKPhysicsBody.init(circleOfRadius: self.radius)
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        print("ball physicsbody is init")
        self.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.2
        self.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }     
}
```

Comment: Are you creating these balls in code, or in the editor and subclassing them in the editor?

Comment: what do you mean by "editor"? I create them inside my 'touchesBegan' function right now (in the future I would like to create them randomly in the scene) - by using 'let ball = Ballnode(radius: 65)'

Comment: I meant in the scene editor. where you can drag and drop sprites into the scene. The .sks file.

Comment: oh, so I creating them inside my code.

Comment: I don't know if you need the "convenience" init. You could just put the code in init. Also, use SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.radius). Not sure if the .init() for the physicsbody is messing it up. I would set the bitmasks like I said in the other question as well. And make sure that print statement is printing, otherwise you know none of this code is running.